# Remove curved edges from thumbnails in gallery (elementor)

Tags: gallery, thumbnails

Im using basic Elementor and it is automatically curving the edges on the thumbnail images in my gallery. I would like clean crisp edges, does anyone know how to do this.

Here is the example on my page : http://www.rosannadean.com/archive/

Comment: You'll have to ask Elementor's support streams. [Third-party plugin/theme questions are off topic here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The reason they are curving is because they have a border-radius set to 5px. Go to Elementors edit gallery then click on the "style" tab and you should see border-radius there. Edit this to be "0 0 0 0" and it will make your corners straight.

[image]